# Log in without forms using Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying write login page without play`s forms and send login data  using post request. After sending post tequets my login page not redirecting to main page.

How i can do this task ?

My code

routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /login                      controllers.Application.login
POST    /login                      controllers.Application.auth
```

login page

```
<body>
        <h1>Play! Login Sample - Login</h1>
        <p>Please provide your credentials.</p>
        <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"></p>
        <p>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" id="loginbutton" onclick="auth();return false">Login</button>
        </p>
        <script>
                function auth( ){
                    var user = $("input[name=email]").val();
                    var pass = $("input[name=password]").val();
                    console.log(user+" "+pass)
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var url = "/login";
                    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/json");
                    var data = JSON.stringify({"name":user, "pass":pass});
                    xhr.send(data);
                    console.log(xhr.status)
                }
        </script>
    </body>
```

controllers:

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }
  def login = Action{
    Ok(views.html.login("Some Message"))
  }

  def auth =Action{
    implicit request =>
      request.body.asJson.map { json =>
        (json \ "name").asOpt[String].map { name =>
          if (name =="some_name "){
            Redirect(routes.Application.index())
          }
          else NoContent
        }.getOrElse {
          BadRequest("Missing parameter [name]")
        }
      }.getOrElse {
        BadRequest("Expecting Json data")
      }       
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the client in the case if controller responds with a redirect.
Before the `xhr.send` add the response processor:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        window.location = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

Update controller:

```
 Redirect(routes.Application.index())
```

to

```
... = Action { implicit request => {
 ...
 Ok(routes.Application.index().absoluteURL())
```

Comment: as xhr.responseText i got my main page html

Comment: never do this with redirect, so I see now that XMLHttpRequest follows 303 redirect and it is impossible to prevent it. I propose you to return the url to the main page and check the response on 200 code, and redirect then. I will update the answer

Comment: Updated with the absolute url response